# rails 3 find command not working with postgresql database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, boolean

I'm using ruby 1.9.2 and rails 3 with a postgresql 8.4 database.

I have the following piece of rails code.

```
@playersonline = Member.find(:all, :conditions => ["loggedIn = ?", true] )
```

And I get the following error when the line is encountered:

```
PGError: ERROR:  column "loggedin" does not exist
```

Looking at the query it generates it shows the following:

```
SELECT     "members".* FROM       "members"  WHERE     (loggedIn = 't')
```

The loggedIn column does exist in my table, and it has a boolean data type.

Another thing that is odd, when I try to query just the loggedIn column via a sql browser I get the same error? i.e. select loggedIn from members

Thanks

Comment: It seems like your problem is in the database, not rails. Can it be a column name case issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Postgres is **case-sensitive** by default so `loggedIn` isn't the same as `loggedin`. Although you can override it, Rails convention is that variable name-parts are separates by an underscore.

I wouldn't recommend re-inventing the wheel. Go in and change the columnn name (and any other columns that follow your notation) you might have to `logged_in`. This will prevent you from encountering any more strange errors.

Comment: Perfect, all columns renamed and working now. Relatively new to rails so forgot about its naming conventions. Thanks Chuck